# Restarting nginx in a Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

My Docker container doesn't seem to have the `service` command. How would I restart `nginx`?

E.g.

```
# uname -r
3.13.0-119-generic
bash-4.3# uname -a
Linux <container id> 3.13.0-119-generic #166-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 3 12:18:55 UTC 2017 x86_64 Linux
bash-4.3# service nginx restart
bash: service: command not found
```

Comment: Have you considered restarting the container?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on whether your container is running systemd or sysV or upstart.

Valid choices at this point are

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

and

```
systemctl restart nginx
```